# sfError404Exception: Action "advantages/index" does not exist

Tags: symfony1, http-status-code-404

I am using Symfony 1.4.
I have a problem, I get a sfError404Exception the URL that I just created.
http://monsite/frontend_dev.php/advantages

This is the message given:

```
404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
Action "advantages/index" does not exist.
```

And I can not understand why.

Here is my folder tree:

1. modules

   - advantages

     - actions

       - action.class.php
     - templates

       - indexSuccess.php

Here's the PHP code I put:

```
<?php
class advantagesActions extends sfActions
{
    public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
        die('oki');
    }
}
?>
```

I do not understand what I forgot, do you have an idea?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action file should be called `actions.class.php` and not `action.class.php`

What does your routing look like?